# Google doc merge on edit of specific cell in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have found below the following code which performs a merge between a google doc and data from a google sheet using the column heading values as the keys to replace text placeholders in the google doc.

```
// Set up the docs and the spreadsheet access

 var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(),
     copyId = copyFile.getId(),
     copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId),
     copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection(),
     activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
     numberOfColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn(),
     activeRowIndex = activeSheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex(),
     activeRow = activeSheet.getRange(activeRowIndex, 1, 1, 
     numberOfColumns).getValues(),
     headerRow = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
     columnIndex = 0

// Replace the keys with the spreadsheet values

    for (;columnIndex < headerRow[0].length; columnIndex++) {

    copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[0][columnIndex] + '%', 
                     activeRow[0][columnIndex])
```

At the moment, this code has to be triggered manually and will perform the function based on where the active row that is selected by the cursor.

Alternatively, I would like to trigger the function on edit of a specific cell in a row, and perform the merge in reference to the values in this same row. I have used the following code in the past to do so but not in the context above.

```
function onEditcustom(e) {

   if(e.range.getColumn() == 1 && e.value == "APPROVED" && 
   e.range.getSheet().getName() == "Sheet 1"){
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question(s)? StackOverflow is not the place to get ad hoc  solutions for your projects from others.

Comment: Hey Anton - to clarify, I would like to know how I can perform a document merge with a google sheet when only when a specific cell is edited. The first set of code above is the gist of it but I would like to perform the function on edit of a specific cell.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the installable trigger `onEdit` in Google Sheets. You have to use the installable version in order to access the DocumentApp service.

You should also note, the `onEdit` can only be used in sheets and not in a document.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers

Comment: Hi Jordan! thanks for the reply. To clarify, the script is in the google sheet and not in the google doc. Would you have any idea on how I can perform the function above only when I edit a specific cell of a row?

Comment: Great. In the docs you can see there are two ways to use the installable trigger, manually and programmatically. It looks like you already have the function written, you just need to go into the script editor and install the trigger.

Comment: Hey Jordan! Thanks again - i know how to run the trigger. However, I'm just having trouble with the code itself. The way the first code is written, it will only trigger when it is manually run. Any thoughts?